# How to combine two internal PHP functions?

Tags: php, function

I have two code blocks that are PHP functions that do two different things. They are:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('UserPhotoDefaultUrl')) {
   function UserPhotoDefaultUrl($User) {
      $Email = GetValue('Email', $User);
      $HTTPS = GetValue('HTTPS', $_SERVER, '');
      $Protocol =  (strlen($HTTPS) || GetValue('SERVER_PORT', $_SERVER) == 443) ? 'https://secure.' : 'http://www.';

      $Url = $Protocol.'gravatar.com/avatar.php?'
         .'gravatar_id='.md5(strtolower($Email))
         .'&amp;size='.C('Garden.Thumbnail.Width', 50);

      if (C('Plugins.Gravatar.UseVanillicon', FALSE))
         $Url .= '&amp;default='.urlencode(Asset('http://vanillicon.com/'.md5($Email).'.png'));
      else
         $Url .= '&amp;default='.urlencode(Asset(C('Plugins.Gravatar.DefaultAvatar', 'plugins/Gravatar/default.gif'), TRUE));

      return $Url;
   }
}
```

and...

```
<?php
class GravatarPlugin extends Gdn_Plugin {
   public function ProfileController_AfterAddSideMenu_Handler($Sender, $Args) {
      if (!$Sender->User->Photo) {
         $Email = GetValue('Email', $Sender->User);
         $Hash = md5($Email);
         $Sender->User->Photo = 'http://w'.substr($Hash, 0, 1).'.vanillicon.com/'.$Hash.'_200.png';
      }
   }
}
```

The first shows the Gravatar image for User avatar in post content of my script (Vanilla forums), and the second one shows the Vanillicons ([Vanillicon](http://vanillicon.com/) is similar to Gravatar) of all the users participating in a discussion in the sidebar (under 'In This Discussion'). I hope you get the idea as to what the two code blocks do now?

Using the how-it's-done code in the first code block, I need to modify the second code block to show Gravatar icons of all users participating in a discussion instead of Vanillicons. Can someone who knows PHP help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('UserPhotoDefaultUrl')) {
   function UserPhotoDefaultUrl($User) {
      $Email = GetValue('Email', $User);
      $HTTPS = GetValue('HTTPS', $_SERVER, '');
      $Protocol =  (strlen($HTTPS) || GetValue('SERVER_PORT', $_SERVER) == 443) ? 'https://secure.' : 'http://www.';

      $Url = $Protocol.'gravatar.com/avatar.php?'
     .'gravatar_id='.md5(strtolower($Email))
     .'&amp;size='.C('Garden.Thumbnail.Width', 50)
     .'&amp;default='.urlencode(Asset(C('Plugins.Gravatar.DefaultAvatar', 'plugins/Gravatar/default.gif'), TRUE));

      return $Url;
   }
}
```

you class:

```
<?php
class GravatarPlugin extends Gdn_Plugin {
   public function ProfileController_AfterAddSideMenu_Handler($Sender, $Args) {
      if (!$Sender->User->Photo) {
       $Sender->User->Photo = UserPhotoDefaultUrl($Sender->User); // not sure about the $Sender->User part because it is not displayed
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But the code is still displaying only the user's default avatar and not gravatar. :(

Comment: No, I probably didn't explain properly. Only the second code block needs to be changed, and it should be standalone code.

Comment: I think this will help me — can you tell me how to combine these two? `function ProfileController_AfterAddSideMenu_Handler($Sender, $Args) {` + `function UserPhotoDefaultUrl($User, $Options = array()) {`